# Running into an issue printing asccii-art shadow character

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding, unicode-string

I wrote a program to do a specific purpose. When I run the program I have an ASCII art banner that writes to a txt document followed by some parsed data that the program generates. The program runs fine without the specific character, however when I attempt to write '█' to a text file, I receive the following error.

File "REDACT.py", line REDACT, in 
report.write('█')
File "C:\Users\REDACT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: character maps to

It would seem that notepad can display and print the character just fine, but some encoding within python cannot recognize the character. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you open a text file for writing without specifying an encoding, Python will pick some platform-dependent default, in your case apparently CP-1252 («Windows Latin-1»). That codec doesn't support the character you want to write. If you want control over the output encoding, specify it in the `open` call: `open(..., encoding=CODEC)`. A good choice for `CODEC` is generally `"utf8"`, but if you work with Notepad I'd go with `"utf-8-sig"`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The default character encoding for US and Western European Windows versions is `Windows-1252` (a.k.a `cp1252`) and only supports a small subset of the entire Unicode character range.  Use a UTF encoding such as `utf8` instead.

Example (be sure to save source file with UTF-8 encoding):

```py
with open('banner.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    print('''\
╔═════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ████    █   █   █ █   █ █████ ████  ║
║ █   █  █ █  ██  █ ██  █ █     █   █ ║
║ ████  █████ █ █ █ █ █ █ ███   █████ ║
║ █   █ █   █ █  ██ █  ██ █     █  █  ║
║ ████  █   █ █   █ █   █ █████ █   █ ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════╝''',file=f)
```

**banner.txt** below. From the terminal, use `chcp 65001` to switch the code page to display UTF-8 text files, but Notepad and Notepad++ will display it correctly as well.  If an editor has problems, use `utf-8-sig`.  Some expect a UTF-8-encoded BOM (byte order mark) character at the start of the file or will default to a localized encoding like `cp1252` instead.

```
C:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\type banner.txt
╔═════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ████    █   █   █ █   █ █████ ████  ║
║ █   █  █ █  ██  █ ██  █ █     █   █ ║
║ ████  █████ █ █ █ █ █ █ ███   █████ ║
║ █   █ █   █ █  ██ █  ██ █     █  █  ║
║ ████  █   █ █   █ █   █ █████ █   █ ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════╝
```